# Replace a character in Terminal

Tags: ubuntu, replace, terminal, character

I have a file.

My second line begins with a '#' symbol.

Which command should I use to remove that symbol?

Also on the third line, I have to put a '#' symbol at the beginning of the line.

For example:

```
line 2: # url: http//192.168.1.1:8000
line 3:   url: http//example.com
```

when running the command, change the place of that '#'

Alternativly, is there a way to put the local IP in second line automatically?  (So if I restart the router for example, the line will refresh the IP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sed`:

```
sed -i~ '2 s/^#//' filename
```

- `-i~` will create a backup
- `2` is the line number where the next command will be applied
- `s/ pattern / replacement /` is a substitution. Here, we substitute with nothing.
- `^` in a pattern matches the start of a line.

To remove the octothorpe from the second line and add it to the third one, use

```
sed -i~ '2 s/^#//; 3 s/^/#/' filename
```

Comment: Thanks! What if I want to do the same, just with '//' smybols instead of the '#'?

Comment: @BalázsOrbán: Use different delimiters, e.g. `s=^//==`.